Polarization in a 3-level system
I am asking this question from a molecular physics perspective (i.e. diatomic molecule placed in an external electric field), but it's quite general in terms of the formulation. I have a 2-level system (call the levels $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$) that can be connected by an electric field through the Stark interaction. The Hamiltonian of the system is (I call the energies of the 2 levels in the absence of electric field $E_1$ and $E_2$):
$$\tag1
\begin{pmatrix}
E_0      & -D_{01}E \\
-D_{01}E & E_1
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
with $D_{01} = \left<0|D|1\right>$. If I diagonalize this, I get (say for the lowest energy state), something of the form: $\left|\tilde0\right> = a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>$, with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. Then, the polarization in the ground state is given by:
$$\tag2p = \frac{\left<\tilde0|D|\tilde0\right>}{D_{01}}$$
Thus, for a very small external field, $|b|$ is very small and the polarization is close to zero, while for a very large field, I have $|a|=|b|=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and thus the polarization is 1, as expected i.e. the molecule is fully polarized in a large external field. However, if I add a 3rd level, connected to $\left|1\right>$ by a dipole interaction, the Hamiltonian becomes:
$$\tag3
\begin{pmatrix}
       E_0 & -D_{01}E   & 0 \\
-D_{01}E   &        E_1 & -D_{12}E \\
0          & -D_{12}E   &        E_2
\end  {pmatrix}
$$
with $D_{12} = \left<1|D|2\right>$ (which doesn't need to be equal to $D_{01}$ in general and I also assume that the dipoles are real numbers). Now, the ground state wavefunction is $\left|\tilde0\right> = a\left|0\right>+b\left|1\right>+c\left|2\right>$, but I am not sure how to define the polarization anymore. I know I still need to take the expectation value: $\left<\tilde0|D|\tilde0\right> = 2abD_{01}+2bcD_{12}$ but I am not sure what to divide this by (the same way I divided by $D_{01}$ before), or if I need a different definition. I know I need to have the same behaviour i.e. close to zero polarization at low field and close to 1 at high field, but I am not sure how to get this in the case of multiple levels.

Polarization is usually dipole moment per unit volume, i.e. $\mathscr{N} \langle \mathbf p \rangle$ where $\mathscr{N}$ is density of molecules and $\mathbf p$ is average dipole moment vector. Why are you dividing expectation value of $D$ by $D_{01}$ and calling that quantity polarization?

Is your question really about how to define polarization (in the sense of vector $\mathbf P$ in EM theory) in general?

Let's analyse this question by a pure algebraic perspective. What you are calling by the lowest energy state $|\tilde{0}\rangle$ is actually an arbitrary state vector, since its coefficients in the original basis are arbitrary. We want to find a normalization constant $N$ such that
$$
p = \frac 1N \langle\tilde{0}|D|\tilde{0}\rangle
$$
Is always bounded by $1$. So we must choose $N$ equals the maximum value the nominator could have, i.e.,
$$
N = \left|\underset{|v\rangle \in \mathrm C^3}{\text{max}}\langle v|D|v\rangle \right|
$$
But it is simple the modulus of the greatest eigenvalue of $D$, so
$$
p = \frac {1}{|\lambda_{max}(D)|} \langle \tilde 0|D|\tilde 0\rangle
$$

Let's check if this definition recovers what we know in the first case (with only dipole interaction between $0$ and $1$). We have
$$
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & D_{01}\\
D_{01} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's straightforward to check that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_\pm = \pm D_{01}$, so clearly $N = |\lambda_{max}(D) |= D_{01}$ as it should.

Now, for the three level case, we have
$$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & D_{01}& 0\\
D_{01} & 0& D_{12}\\
0 & D_{12}& 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{D_{01}^2 + D_{12}^2}$, so we define
$$
p = \frac {\langle\tilde{0}|D|\tilde{0}\rangle}{\sqrt{D_{01}^2 + D_{12}^2}}
$$

You should ask why to analyse it by pure algebraic arguments, since we are in PSE. The reason is simple: a normalization is always an arbitrary choice. There are no normalized quantities in nature!
